# cant manage to get the word count?

Tags: java

Essentially im trying to get the word count for a word that ive already addded to the arraylist
(using the addWord method ). At first i tried using streams but i gave up, now im trying to use a relatively easier iterator method .i just cant get it to work(i always get 0). Any help would be appreciated

Main method

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple 'driver' for the WordAnalyser class.
 * 
 * Split a 'document' into individual words and pass them
 * to a WordAnalyser to be analysed.
 * 
 * In this example, the 'document' is a String literal in
 * the main method, but this could easily be changed to an
 * external file, if desired (e.g., use a Scanner).
 * 
 * Print a few sample statistics.
 *
 */
public class WordAnalyserMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String document = 
            "The first day of the third month was always difficult for Joy because there was little to look forward to in the month of March.";
        String[] words = document.split("[ ,.;:?]+");
        WordAnalyser analyser = new WordAnalyser();
        for(String word : words) {
            analyser.addWord(word);
        }
        for(String word : List.of("The", "the", "joy", "was")) {
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println("    " + analyser.getCount(word));
            System.out.println("    " + analyser.getCaseInsensitiveCount(word));
            System.out.println("    " + analyser.followedBy(word, "month"));
        }
    }
}
```

My wordAnalyser class so far

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Keep track of word counts and word pairs.
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 
 */
public class WordAnalyser
{    
    private HashMap<String,Integer> counts;
    private ArrayList<String> WordAnalyser;
    private String wordCounts;
    private String Sentences;
    private int count;
    private Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class WordAnalyser
     */
    public WordAnalyser()
    {
        counts = new HashMap<>();
        WordAnalyser = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Uses a for each loop to add the input, starting from 0 
     */
    public void addWord(String input)
    {
        WordAnalyser.add(input);
        this.counts = counts;
        for (String word : WordAnalyser)
        {
            int counter = counts.getOrDefault(word , 0);
            counts.put(word,counter +1);
            System.out.println(input);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of times the given word has been seen.
     * @param word The word to be looked up.
     * @return The number of times the word has been seen.
     */

    public int getCount(String word)
    {
        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        this.count=count;
        for(String words: WordAnalyser) {
            Integer count = wordCount.get(words);          
            wordCount.put(words, (count== null) ? 1 : count+1);

        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are looping all the words everytime you add a word. You should remove the for loop in `addWord`

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
private Map<String, Integer> save;

public void addWord(String word) {
    if(save.containsKey(word)) {
        save.put(word, save.get(word)+1);
    } else {
        save.put(word, 1);
    }
}

public int getCount(String word) {
    return save.containsKey(word) ? save.get(word) : 0;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use one map here. As I did. Furthermore: Please don't use names like `private ArrayList<String> WordAnalyser;` Instead you could call it: `wordAnalyser`. Pascal Case is used for class-names. For variable names it is used camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
public class WordAnalyser {
    private ArrayList<String> WordAnalyser;
    private String wordCounts;
    private String Sentences;
    private int count;
    private Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class WordAnalyser
     */
    public WordAnalyser() {
        wordCount = new HashMap<>();
        WordAnalyser = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Uses a for each loop to add the input, starting from 0
     */
    public void addWord(String input) {
        WordAnalyser.add(input);
        int counter = wordCount.getOrDefault(input, 0);
        wordCount.put(input, counter + 1);
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of times the given word has been seen.
     *
     * @param word The word to be looked up.
     * @return The number of times the word has been seen.
     */

    public int getCount(String word) {
        Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
        if ( count == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

- You can use the map `wordCount` to store the number of times a word is repeated.
- You do not need to loop all the elements everytime a new element is added.
- When you require the count of a specific word, you can just check if `wordCount` has the word as key, or return 0.